# Tensorflow lite image output different between python and iOS/Android

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow-lite

I convert Keras model to TF lite the output dimension is (1, 256, 256, 1).
the result on python is correct, but when I try to construct the image on ios swift the result is wrong.

Here is the code, that I use to construct an UIImage from a list of output.

```
// helper function
---------------------------------------
// MARK: - Extensions
extension Data {
  init<T>(copyingBufferOf array: [T]) {
    self = array.withUnsafeBufferPointer(Data.init)
  }

  /// Convert a Data instance to Array representation.
  func toArray<T>(type: T.Type) -> [T] where T: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral {
    var array = [T](repeating: 0, count: self.count/MemoryLayout<T>.stride)
    _ = array.withUnsafeMutableBytes { copyBytes(to: $0) }
    return array
  }
}

func imageFromSRGBColorArray(pixels: [UInt32], width: Int, height: Int) -> UIImage?
{
    guard width > 0 && height > 0 else { return nil }
    guard pixels.count == width * height else { return nil }

    // Make a mutable copy
    var data = pixels

    // Convert array of pixels to a CGImage instance.
    let cgImage = data.withUnsafeMutableBytes { (ptr) -> CGImage in
      let ctx = CGContext(
        data: ptr.baseAddress,
        width: width,
        height: height,
        bitsPerComponent: 8,
        bytesPerRow: MemoryLayout<UInt32>.size * width,
        space: CGColorSpace(name: CGColorSpace.sRGB)!,
        bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Little.rawValue
          + CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedFirst.rawValue
      )!
      return ctx.makeImage()!
    }

    // Convert the CGImage instance to an UIImage instance.
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
  }

   let results = outputTensor.data.toArray(type: UInt32.self)

   let maskImage = imageFromSRGBColorArray(pixels: results, width: 256, height: 256)
```

the result I get is completely wrong compared to python.
I think the function imageFromSRGBColorArray is not correct.
can anyone help me to figure out the problem?